# chrome: why does localStorage also contains sessionStorage data?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, token, amazon-cognito, session-storage

I am using AWS Cognito for my web app and testing with Chrome browser.

I started with the default AWS Cognito / Amplify configurations, such that the tokens are stored in chrome localStorage. When I close browser and re-opens it, I can still login without entering username and password again.

Now I changed AWS Cognito / Amplify configurations to

```
Auth.configure({ storage: window.sessionStorage })
```

such that tokens should be stored in chrome `sessionStorage` and users automatically log out when closing the tab/browser.

I have confirmed that it works - I see tokens appear in sessionStorage and I indeed have logged out when closing the tab/browser.

However, I still see tokens appear in localStorage, and even though they are in localStorage, they do not survive tab closing:

As you can see in sessionStorage, access/id/refresh tokens are red-lined:

[image]

And in localStorage, access/id/refresh tokens are also there:
[image]

However, they do not survive tab closing.

Why are they there?

Comment: I think it has something to do with website cache in my browser. I was doing tab close all the time. After I quit chrome and re-opens it, the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to clear site data (Application browser's tab)
Because `Auth.configure({ storage:<your_storage> })` sets it up in appropriate storage only